# How is 那还用说！translated as "Of course!" or "That goes without saying!"?

Tags: translation, meaning

Could anyone please tell me how these characters mean "Of course!"/"That goes without saying!" when placed together?

Because when it's translated one by one, the characters don't seem to correlate to one another at all.

```
那 : that
还 : still
用 : use
说 : speak
```

I'm just curious though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is [用](http://dict.youdao.com/w/%E7%94%A8/#keyfrom=dict2.top) doesn't mean "use", but "need" here.

> （多用于否定: 需要） need:
>
> ```
> There's no need to turn on the light.
> 不用开灯。
>
> I don't think you need to worry in the least.
> 我看你一点也不用着急。
> ```

And [还](http://dict.youdao.com/w/eng/%E8%BF%98/#keyfrom=dict2.index) is used for emphasis,

> （用以加强语气）:
>
> ```
> That goes without saying.
> 那还用说!
>
> This is the limit!; This is simply atrocious!
> 这还了得!
> ```

那还用说 is a rhetorical question (echo question), it literally means ”need to say that?!", i.e. "no need to say", then "of course" or "that goes without saying".

Comment: So is 这还用说 to be interpreted as a question?

Comment: @BallpointBen Yes, a rhetorical question.

Answer (score 4):

那还用说！ means "**not even deserves to mention it**", implying ***something is very obvious and no need to address it or put it on the table***.

Stretch a bit:

**那**：that thing

**还用**（equal to 不用）：not necessary to

**说**：speak, mention